# PHP JPGraphs - Tightening up the image

Tags: php, graph

What functions are there to customise the graph, for example the width of the bars and the spaces between the bars.
I would like to reduce the gaps between the bars, and between the month labels.

What are there any functions that can perform these alterations?

Comment: How about reading the documentation first? http://jpgraph.net/doc/

Comment: Would rather not read 700 pages! I have been browsing through it alrite, but cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to adjust the width of the columns (and possibly the graph itself).

You can use the function `BarPlot::SetWidth($aWidth)` to set the column width (see also [this example](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15s02.html#fig.example22)). This function is described in the class documentation [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/BarPlot.html#_BARPLOT_SETWIDTH):

> Specify width as fractions of the major step size when the scale used is a text scale (which is the normal scale to use for bars). If the X-axis scale is a linear scale (i.e. lin, int or date) then the width must be specified in absolute pixels.

Therefore you can either set the width of the columns as a percentage or as an absolute pixel width.

- To set the width as a percentage, use a value <= 1. 
  e.g. 25% `$barplot->SetWidth(0.25);`
- To set the width in pixels, use a value > 1.
  e.g. 56 pixels `$barplot->SetWidth(56);`

Have a fiddle around until you get something you're happy with.

Comment: Other stuff that helped: 
$graph->SetMargin(30,1,20,5);  
$graph->SetBox();  
$graph->SetFrame(false);  $graph->SetScale("textlin");